# In Java code running on Linux, how to point to a shared Windows folder?

Tags: java, linux, file, java-io, mount

I have a shared Windows folder:

\servername.domain.com\dir\warname

This is how I access it from Java code running on Windows OS:

```
// \dir
String directory = getInitParameter ("directory");

// /warname
final String contextPath = this.getServletContext().getContextPath(); 

// \dir/warname
directory += (directory.endsWith("/") ? contextPath.substring(1) : contextPath); 

// //servername.domain.com/\dir/warname

directory = "//" + getDatabaseServerName() + (directory.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + directory;

// \\servername.domain.com\dir\warname
File shareDir = new File(directory);

if (!shareDir.exists()) {
        if (!shareDir.mkdirs()) { 
            throw new Exception ("Error: " + shareDir + " does not exist and could not be created.");
        }
    }
```

From this point forward, I can access the \servername.domain.com\dir\warname and write to it.

If this code runs on Linux server, this is what I get:

```
directory: //servername.domain.com/\dir/warname

shareDir: /severname.domain.com/\dir/warname
```

And then the above exp. will be thrown:

```
java.lang.Exception: Error: /servername.domain.com/\dir/warname does not exist and could not be created.
```

So it tries to create a new dir and it fails.

How can I point to the same shared Windows folder from Linux?

I did Google search it but was not able to find the solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You _do_ know you shouldn't use backslashes \ in paths on Linux/Unix? In Java, using a forward slash `/` in paths works on Windows just fine, so I advise you stick with that in code. You avoid having to double `\\\` and you're more portable. In fact, using '/' in file-handling calls to the OS has worked since the days of _MS-DOS_ ... it was only the command line, _command.com_, that didn't like forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install the SMB client on Linux. See this article on how to do that: http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/

Comment: Once that's done, does Java code recognizes the folder or Java changes are required?

Comment: SMB shared folders must be mounted on Linux FS (ie `/mnt/server.domain.com/dir/...`) then it will be accessible like any other file.